# Signing JWT token using pem key converted from Google service account .p12 key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, service-accounts

Here I'm trying to sign a JWT token for google's API access from the front-end. I created a service account, downloaded the p12 key and converted it to pem key using the following command

```
openssl pkcs12 -in privatekey.p12 -nodes -nocerts --passin pass:notasecret > privateKey.pem
```

I then used the npm package jsonwebtoken to return a token using the following code which works for my server side code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const private_key_file = 'privateKey.pem';
const algorithm = 'RS256';
const projectId = [PROJECT_ID];

function createJwt (projectId, private_key_file, algorithm) {
    // Create a JWT to authenticate this device. The device will be disconnected
    // after the token expires, and will have to reconnect with a new token. The
    // audience field should always be set to the GCP project id.
    const token = {
      'iat': parseInt(Date.now() / 1000),
      'exp': parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) + 1000,
      'aud': projectId
    };
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(private_key_file);
    return jwt.sign(token, private_key_file, { algorithm: algorithm });
};

console.log(createJwt(projectId, private_key_file, algorithm));
```

However, I keep running into error that Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line. I'm aware that this means somehow the pem file is not properly detected. I've gone in and checked that there are some precursor lines like

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: privateKey
    localKeyID: xx xx xx ...
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
....
....
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Before and after removing it to only show the BEGIN up to END PRIVATE KEY, I also checked using the following command to see that it does load the key file properly.

```
openssl rsa -text -noout -in privateKey.pem
```

But even so, when I used node to run the JWT signing code the error message still returns Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line. Would be great if someone could help point out where I did wrong or suggest a general direction I can look into, thanks!

Comment: Ahh.. this is embarrassing.. I passed the wrong variable into my jwt.sign function.. const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(private_key_file);
    return jwt.sign(token, privateKey, { algorithm: algorithm });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a silly mistake in my code, it should be the following and now the token gets successfully returned.

```
   const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(private_key_file);
   return jwt.sign(token, **privateKey**, { algorithm: algorithm });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. This was helpful.